# is javaSE oracle certification mandatory for doing javaEE oracle certification?

Tags: java, oracle

i want to do java EE oracle certification, but i dont have javaSE certification. i am interested in web development so i prefer doing javaEE certification. now my doubt is whether javaSE certification is required for doing javaEE certification?

Comment: What do you need certification for?

Comment: @GermannArlington ... what?

Comment: @eis I never knew that you need certifications to do software development...

Comment: @GermannArlington did someone claim that you need them in order to do software development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, unless you can/want to go directly to Oracle Certified Master, Enterprise Architect certification.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Certification_Program):

[image]

The certifications listed on "Oracle Certified Expert", Business Component Developer and Enterprise Architect relate to Java EE technologies.

Answer (score 0):

For current version "Oracle Certified Professional, Java EE 7 Application Developer", you need to pass in only one exam.

[Oracle Certified Professional, Java EE 7 Application Developer](https://education.oracle.com/products/trackp_900)